# Execute each test method in a forked VM without concurrency

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am trying to execute each method of a JUnit test into a separated VM without executing all the methods at the same time. I want to serialize the execution of the test methods using a separated VM for each of them.

I have tried several configuration and checked the [Maven plugin documentation about forked VM](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) but I did not manage to get the correct behavior.

I am using the following configuration but all the methods are executed at the same time.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCountMethods>1</threadCountMethods>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of threads is counted by code by default (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#perCoreThreadCount). The following configuration is working.

```
<configuration>
     <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
     <parallel>methods</parallel>
     <threadCount>1</threadCount>
     <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
 </configuration>
```